# Safari not showing posts pictures of wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, safari

I recently came across a strange bug in my project concerning Safari and a post grid. Safari doesn't show the post pictures, only after loading one post site. Chromium- based browsers, FireFox and Edge work fine. The url is https://superwien.com/news/.

Here's a link to the video showing the problem: https://youtu.be/_o-SFCFKmzE

I don't know where to start looking to solve the issue.

Comment: Welcome! Please read why [my site isn't working here's a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) isn't a good question. Include the minimal amount of code to show us the issue here.

Comment: As a note, it looks like it's the JS for the portfolio module. If you resize the screen, it triggers the refresh. For some reason, Safari isn't recognizing the initial load and is probably a lazy loading issue. Do you have a cache plugin like WP Rocket?

Comment: I felt stupid asking the question and I'm thankful you looked into it. Yes, WP Rocket is installed.

Comment: It's definitely WP Rocket then. In the Defer or Delay JS scripts section, you should add `oshine-modules` to both boxes, even if disabled. It seems like that's causing some issues. Or at least remove that from the JS minification. I bet if you turned off rocket the issue goes away.

Comment: thank you. something else than rocket causes the problem. even removing rocket didn't solve it. i'm investigating further. 

BE GDPR Compliance
BE Portfolio Post
Blog Designer
Blog Designer Pack
Duplicate Page
Filterable Portfolio
Font Awesome
Interactive Geo Maps
ManageWP - Worker
Master Slider Pro
Max Mega Menu
Meta Box
Meta Box Conditional Logic
Meta Box Show Hide
Meta Box Tabs
Oshine Core
Oshine Modules
Portfolio Gallery
Solid Security Pro
TablePress
Tatsu
The Post Grid
WP File Manager
WP Go Maps (formerly WP Google Maps)
WP Mail SMTP
WP Show Posts
WPCode Lite

Comment: you wanna have a guess? thanks for your support :).

Comment: I'm not going to guess, that's too many plugins. Disable them all and then turn them on one by one until the issue happens. Good luck!